# ORMLite initialize foreign collection

Tags: java, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have foreign collection field on my Object.
If I create Object > save it > query for it : then I have it and can use it.
But if I create Object and try to access foreign collection field right away then it's null.
How can I initialize it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As part of the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) Dao class, there is an [`assignEmptyForeignCollection(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#assignEmptyForeignCollection%28T,%20java.lang.String%29).  This creates an empty collection for you and assigns it to the proper field.

To quote from the [Javadocs for the method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#assignEmptyForeignCollection%28T,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Creates an empty collection and assigns it to the appropriate field in the parent object. This allows you to add things to the collection from the start. For example let's say you have an Account which has the field:

Comment: I observed, that the collection is not empty if the entity already is referenced in the database. I need to find a way to update my foreign collections. According to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39883622/663551 

I am thinking about somehow abusing the methode named above.